# Are there different symbols for "database server" vs "database"?

Tags: diagrams

I am writing some user documentation where I need to depict a Microsoft Server Express installed on a computer. (Note: in my user documentation, the idea is that Microsoft Server Express is installed on a computer that is used for typical end-user activities, such as word processing; it is not installed on a computer that is dedicated for the purpose of being a server).

My understanding is that Microsoft Server Express is a database server, because multiple databases can be "put into" it; and then any client can say to MS Server Express "please serve me the database named XYZ".

I know I have seen the [cylindrical "hard drive" symbol](https://openclipart.org/detail/190410/simple-database-icon) used to represent a database. Is this the same symbol used to represent a Database Server, too?

Comment: In my limited experience, "database" is a cylinder (as you said), "server" is a rectangular box (like a computer tower), and "database server" is just a combination of these symbols.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Era. Would you be able to link to any webpage with these pictures?

Comment: http://www.greenwhitesolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/server-dedicate.jpg

Answer (score 5):

This is the symbol for a Database:

[image]

This is the symbol for a Database Server:

[image]

Comment: although this confuses me just a little bit, because the computer tower, to my eyes, looks like a physical computer. Microsoft SQL Server Express is just a program installed on the physical computer, so I didn't think that it would use the "physical computer tower" symbol.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Express is the first symbol, not the second.

Comment: Is not Microsoft SQL Server Express a Database Server? (That is, you can have multiple databases created "within" the same Microsoft SQL Server Express instance that is running).

Comment: Don't overthink this; use the symbol that seems most intuitive for your particular diagram.  Your decision as to which one you should use warrants no more than about 60 seconds of consideration.  If someone objects to your choice, just switch it to the other symbol and get on with life.

Comment: It's a pity the MS SQL Server logo is so poorly designed and is not at all recognizable. Otherwise the classic cilinder with the product logo on top of it would work, or a laptop with the logo in the screen. But the MS SQL Server logo has no brand power and is cumbersome.